# What is the most used pattern in java.io?

Tags: java, design-patterns, io

I was asked this question recently during my job interview, and I couldn't answer it. So, what is the most used pattern in java.io and how is it used? What are other patterns used in common java libraries?

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673841/examples-of-gof-design-patterns/2707195#2707195) for a comprehensive list of GoF patterns used in the Java standard libraries.

Comment: Check this post at Java Code Geeks about design patterns in JDK - http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/03/design-patterns-in-jdk.html

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I guess they wanted to hear about the [Decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) which can be found in the various Streams, Readers and Writers.

Other patterns (small selection):

- [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) in the swing libraries
- [Factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) in the javax.xml.parsers packages
- [Iterator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator_pattern), used in collections

I'm pretty sure that one can find examples for almost all patterns listed on this [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern_%28computer_science%29) in the Java SDK.

Answer (score 33):

[`BufferedReader`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) etc implements [decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). Any [`Reader`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html), e.g. [`FileReader`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html) or [`StringReader`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html), can be *decorated* with the buffering feature, which is really source-oblivious.

---

#### Other patterns

- [`java.util.Comparator<T>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) is a [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)

---

## Anti-patterns

To add to what others have said, these are several *anti*-patterns in the Java libraries:

#### Antipattern: inheritance instead of composition

From *Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 16: Favor composition over inheritance*:

> There are a number of obvious violations of this principle in the Java platform libraries. For example, a stack is not a vector, so [`Stack`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) should not extend [`Vector`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Vector.html). Similarly, a property list is not a hash table, so [`Properties`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) should not extend [`Hashtable`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html). In both cases, composition would have been preferable.

#### Related questions

- [Prefer composition over inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance)
- [java inheritance versus composition (implementing a stack)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419115/java-inheritance-versus-composition-implementing-a-stack)
- [Difference between Inheritance and Composition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399544/difference-between-inheritance-and-composition)
- [Inheritance or composition: Rely on “is-a” and “has-a”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453738/inheritance-or-composition-rely-on-is-a-and-has-a)
- [Object Oriented Best Practices - Inheritance v Composition v Interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216523/object-oriented-best-practices-inheritance-v-composition-v-interfaces)
- [Should I use inheritance or composition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598722/should-i-use-inheritance-or-composition)
- [Inheritance vs. Aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269496/inheritance-vs-aggregation)
- [Aggregation verses Composition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734891/aggregation-verses-composition)
- [Decorator Pattern Using Composition Instead of Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829114/decorator-pattern-using-composition-instead-of-inheritance)

---

#### Antipattern: constant interfaces

From *Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 19: Use interfaces only to define types*:

> There are several constant interfaces in the Java platform libraries, such as [`java.io.ObjectStreamConstants`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectStreamConstants.html). These interfaces should be regarded as anomalies and should not be emulated.

#### Related questions

- [Should a class implement a constants-only interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063473/should-a-class-implement-a-constants-only-interface)
- [What is the best way to implement constants in Java ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66066/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-constants-in-java)

---

#### Antipattern: telescoping constructor and JavaBeans patterns

From *Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 2: Consider a builder when faced with many constructor parameters* ([excerpt online](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/books/EffectiveJava.aspx)):

> Traditionally, programmers have used the *telescoping constructor* pattern, in which you provide a constructor with only the required parameters, another with a single optional parameters, a third with two optional parameters, and so on [...] The telescoping constructor pattern works, but it is hard to write client code when there are many parameters, and harder still to write it.
>
> A second alternative when you are faced with many constructor parameters is the *JavaBeans* pattern, in which you call a parameterless constructor to create the object, and then call setter methods to set each required parameter, and each optional parameter of interest. [...] Unfortunately the JavaBeans pattern has serious disadvantages of its own [...] a JavaBean may be in an inconsistent state partway through its construction [and it] precludes the possibility of making a class immutable.

Bloch recommends using a [builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) instead.

#### Related questions

- [Is this a well known design pattern? What is its name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637268/is-this-a-well-known-design-pattern-what-is-its-name/)
- [What is the difference between Builder Design pattern and Factory Design pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757743/what-is-the-difference-between-builder-design-pattern-and-factory-design-pattern)
- [When would you use the Builder Pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328496/when-would-you-use-the-builder-pattern)

Answer (score 8):

The [decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) is often used in java i/o.

Example

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("filename.txt"));
```

Answer (score 4):

Decorator pattern, I think. To create all flavors of Readers, Writers, input and output streams.
See [this](http://csis.pace.edu/~bergin/patterns/strategydecorator.html), for example.

Answer (score 2):

Patterns used in java.io package.

1. [Decorator_pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

   Examples:

   The abstract class [java.io.FilterInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FilterInputStream.html) and its concrete subclasses : `BufferedInputStream, CheckedInputStream` etc
2. [Abstract_factory_pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) and [Factory_method_pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) patterns:

   Examples:

   The abstract class [InputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html)  and its concrete sub classes:  `ByteArrayInputStream, FileInputStream, FilterInputStream` etc.

   ```
    InputStream input = new FileInputStream("some_file.txt");
   ```

   Below classes enable unification of input from a byte-array, a file, a network connection, a persistent storage, a pipe, a string, etc:

   ```
    class java.io.InputStream 
          class java.io.ByteArrayInputStream 
          class java.io.FileInputStream 
          class java.io.FilterInputStream 
          class java.io.ObjectInputStream
          class java.io.PipedInputStream 
          class java.io.SequenceInputStream 
          class java.io.StringBufferInputStream
   ```

   Examples:

   `java.io.InputStreamReader` translates a byte stream into a character stream, and a `java.io.OutputStreamWriter` translates a character stream into a byte stream.
3. [Template_method_pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern)

   All non-abstract methods of `java.io.InputStream, java.io.OutputStream, java.io.Reader and java.io.Writer`.

For all other patterns in java,  refer to this post:

[Examples of GoF Design Patterns in Java's core libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673841/examples-of-gof-design-patterns-in-javas-core-libraries)