# java.io architecture: FilterI/OStream

Tags: java, java-io

As far as we can see, `FilterInputStream` class extends `InputStream` class. It's simple because `FilterInputStream` instance "is-a" `InputStream` instance. But also there is a field which type is `InputStream` in `FilterInputStream` class, it means that `InputStream` is a "part-of" `FilterInputStream`. They used composition and inheritance both. What kind of problems does this decision solve? What for? Is it just well-known pattern?

Comment: Look up the Decorator pattern

Comment: Just look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068912/what-is-the-most-used-pattern-in-java-io