# Design pattern factory or singleton or abstract factory or builder?

Tags: design-patterns

Hello i am looking for the design pattern of that code:

```
FileInputStream fin=new FileInputStream("X.zip");
BufferedInputStream bin=new BufferedInputStream(fin);
ZipInputStream zin=new ZipInputStream(bin);
```

i think it is a factory design pattern,what do you think guys?

Really there is no pattern,but they told me to give the name of the pattern
in one word,it must be a design pattern since they asking me.

Comment: There's no pattern here,certainly not factory pattern.

Comment: really,they ask me to give the corresponding design pattern name in one word so it must be a design pattern  somewhere in the code

Comment: I really hope this is not for a job interview.

Comment: @TonyStark, this has been a common [interview question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068912/what-is-the-most-used-pattern-in-java-io) for years.

Comment: @DavidG, this is a common interview question. See the link in my comment above and also [Examples of GoF Design Patterns in Java's core libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673841/examples-of-gof-design-patterns-in-javas-core-libraries).

Answer (score 0):

This is the decorator design pattern. With every new instance you are adding new behavior at runtime.

Comment: thank you i think that is what they are looking for as an answer,thanks